# MPI Inter group communication

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

Following my previous question which was marked as too broad, I have tried to narrow my question.Am new in MPI . Had a read on MPI Communictors but still cant get my head around.  For a start, I would basically appreciate a demonstration of how in code can one split a communicator like MPI_COMM_WORLD into MPI_Groups. For example, given a shape e.g. square, the program splits MPI_COMM_WORLD into two groups grpArea and grpPerimeter which compute the area and perimeter of the given shape. These groups should do their private computations and return result to root(rank 0) of MPI_COMM_WORLD. This may not be the best example but it illustrate where am stuck.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Why using groups? Just splitting the communicator using `MPI_Comm_split()` should just do the trick. I'd say that most of the time, playing with MPI_Groups is a bad idea.

Comment: Just to ad to this, if you want to see how MPI_Com_split can be used, I wrote some example a few days ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365752/mpi-bcast-or-scatter-to-specific-ranks/32378653#32378653)

Comment: Thanks , I will have a read . I  realized I dont have  `zlib.h` (  undefined reference to `crc32'
  )  , so I just commented off lines with crc and set color to `rank%2` , that may work for study purposes.

Comment: Actually, using crc32 there was just a convenient way of creating a (hopefully but not 100% guaranteed) unique "color" for each node name. However, another (better but lengthier) solution would have been to use `MPI_All_gather()` to collect all names and to find the first index within the list corresponding to one's name. This index would have just been perfect for our purpose.